# Modify Python variable from another file

Tags: python-2.7, file, subprocess

So let's assume that I have 2 files : file1.py and file2.py

file1.py

```
x = 0
def test():
    subprocess.check_output(['python', 'file2.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
    print x
```

file2.py

```
#somecoderan from the file1command
x=1
```

And when I call the test function I want to print 1. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is it important to use subprocess? Where would your `test()` call be, in `file1.py` or `file2.py`?

Comment: test() will be in file1.py, yes it is important because file2.py is a LibSVM file named easy.py and the whole point of what I am trying to do is to know when easy.py finished its functions.